# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Service Connection Permission

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

Assuming an Azure DevOps pipeline has been authorized to use a service connection.  If the user that is running the pipeline does NOT have permission on the same service connection, will he/she be able to run the pipeline still?  Just want to see which takes precedence.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipeline use the service connection via `pipeline service account` instead of `personal account`. Assuming an Azure DevOps pipeline has been authorized to use a service connection. If the user that is running the pipeline does NOT have permission on the same service connection, He can still run the pipeline

**Test A**

I create a service connection via account A->open service connection->add yaml build in the Pipeline permissions->run the yaml build via account B, it works.

Result:

[image]

**Test B**

If I remove the yaml build in the pipeline permission and run the build, it need to permit the permission

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: Hey Vito Liu.  Thanks for the quick response and taking the time to test it.  So the take-away here is that the pipeline will ignore personal account and use the pipeline service account.